# Calling jQuery Within an Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I currently have an anonymous function that works great to slide content in on a page that includes jQuery, but of course it doesn't work when jQuery isn't included.

How do can I load jQuery via JavaScript and have it work properly?

Here is what I tried:

```
(function(){
  var c=location.protocol;
  var b=c+"//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js";
  var a=document.createElement("script");
  a.type="text/javascript";
  a.src=b;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)
})();



(function($){



var css = "html,body {margin: 0px !important;padding: 0px !important;}#popslide {width: 525px !important;height: 250px !important;border: 2px solid #bcbbba !important;border-right: none !important;border-radius: 4px !important;position: fixed !important;bottom: 15% !important;background: #f5f5f7 !important;color: #717175 !important;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, arial, sans-serif !important;z-index: 500 !important;}#popslide:before {content: '' !important;padding-bottom: 2px !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #dedfdf !important;width: 525px !important;height: 250px !important;display: block !important;position: absolute !important;z-index: -1 !important;border-radius: 3px !important;}#popslide .question {width: 200px !important;position: absolute !important;left: 25px !important;top: 25px !important;}#popslide h1 {font-size: 20px !important;font-weight: 500 !important;color: #545459 !important;}#popslide .question ul {list-style-type: none !important;padding-left: 10px !important;font-size: 13px !important;}#popslide .question ul li {margin-bottom: 6px !important;}#popslide .question input[type='button'] {background: #f12f09 !important;border: none !important;color: #fff !important;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, arial, sans-serif !important;font-weight: 400 !important;font-size: 13px !important;border-radius: 3px !important;padding: 8px 20px !important;margin-top: 4px !important;margin-bottom: 5px !important;cursor: pointer !important;}#popslide .question ul li a {color: #4c8ae0 !important;font-size: 12px !important;}#popslide .question input[type='button']:hover {background: #d12200 !important;}#popslide .thumb {width: 250px !important;height: 200px !important;position: absolute !important;right: 30px !important;top: 25px !important;cursor: pointer !important;}#popslide #close {position: absolute !important;width: 20px !important;left: 6px !important;top: 6px !important;z-index: 600 !important;cursor: pointer !important;opacity:0.4 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=40) !important;}";

$('head').append('<style type="text/css">' + css + '</style>');

$('body').append(
    '<div id="popslide">'
  + '  <img src="close.png" id="close" />'
  + '  <div class="question">'
  + '    <h1>Was this cat drugged by the government?</h1>'
  + '    <ul>'
  + '      <li><input type="radio" name="vote" class="vote" id="vote1"> <label for="vote1">Probably</label></li>'
  + '      <li><input type="radio" name="vote" class="vote" id="vote2"> <label for="vote2">Yes</label></li>'
  + '      <li><input type="button" class="vote" value="Vote" id="vote3"></li>'
  + '      <li><a href="#" id="results">See results</a></li>'
  + '    </ul>'
  + '  </div>'
  + '  <img src="sail.gif" class="thumb" />'
  + '</div>'
  );

  document.getElementById('popslide').style.right = '-' + 540 + 'px'

  var right = -540

  function frame() {
    right += 10
    document.getElementById('popslide').style.right = right + 'px'
    if (right == -10) {
      clearInterval(id)
    }
  }

  var id = setInterval(frame, 10)

  $('#popslide .vote, #results, #popslide .thumb').click(function() {
    alert('BAM!');
  })

  $('#popslide #close').click(function() {
    $('#popslide').fadeOut();
  })

})($);
```

Comment: well, i haven't dissected your the rest of your script to see if there's any problems there, but the jquery script include itself is fine.. probably the issue is jquery isn't loading before your code right after it is trying to make use of it.  Is there any reason why you can't just include it via a regular script include?

Answer (score 3):

You could have just included the jquery with script tag, but with this kind of code you need to check if jQuery is loaded before trying to use it, something like:

```
(function(){  
  var c=location.protocol;
  var b=c+"//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js";
  var a=document.createElement("script");
  a.type="text/javascript";
  if( a.readyState ) {
    a.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if( a.readyState == 'loaded' || a.readyState == 'complete' ) {
          a.onreadystatechange = null;
          loaded();
          }
       };
    }
    else {
      a.onload = function() {
        loaded();
    };
  }
  a.src=b;

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a);
})();
function loaded() {
    var jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict( true );
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //use $ here for jQuery manipulations
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of right now (although not pretty) is to set an interval (small one - 100msec or so) that checks for the existence of `$`. If present, the interval is cleared and your function called.

Also, to improve loading times, you might want to use the minified version of jquery, as it's smaller. Instead of `//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`, use `//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`